# How to import a project from Docker into Android Studio

Tags: docker, android-studio

I am using this repo github.com/opengisch/QField to create a Docker image. It all went ok and I can see the Docker container is running. This runs a local machine and I am not able to see where the files downloaded by Docker are saved on Widows 10. I have not used Docker before.

I need to open this project in Android Studio but I cannot find any guide how to do this. I have tried to locate files and directly download to Windows but dont seem to have any luck.